# ajax load content into div scripts not working (one is one isn't)

Tags: jquery, ajax, scripting, load

Did ask that earlier but noticed something. Got a main page which loads external PHP into a `DIV` using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
$('#content').load('pages/index.php');



// Handle Clicks
$('ul.nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#content').hide().load('pages/' + page + '.php').fadeIn('normal');



    //Wont Redirect
    return false;

});
// /

   });
```

The pages load fine into the `DIV`, but the JavaScripts are playing up. The top one does not work and the bottom one does. Both use

```
 $(function() {
 <script>

    $(function() {

        var target = $('.fademe');
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();
        $(document).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
            if(scrollPercent >= 0){
                target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
            }
        });

    });

    </script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.scrollUp();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the top one does not work"?  Can you show us the HTML that is originally on the page and the HTML that is being loaded later?

Comment: here you go!! main index page - http://pastie.org/7319519 second page which i want to load - http://pastie.org/7319528 been on this all day hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your two `pastie` files, you seem to include the HTML element with the `fademe` class inside the HTML that is loaded later, not in the HTML that is originally on the page.  Therefore your first function will not work, as jQuery will not find any elements with a class of `fademe`.

To make your function work, it needs to be included in the load `callback`.

```
$('#content').load('pages/index.php', function() {

    var target = $('.fademe');
    var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();
    $(document).scroll(function(e){
        var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
        if(scrollPercent >= 0){
            target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry to be a pain not sure what you mean by load callback.. thanks for the reply steve..

Comment: Brillant steve.. thats got it working.. thanks for the help really appreciate it.. been rattling my brain for hours...

Comment: Great. If it helped you, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: sorry to be a pain again steve, do you know how i load my external js file for my twitter feed <script src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/AllyCallow.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=5" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attaching event handlers to a non-existing (yet) DOM Element, because you are a ajax content, so ajax is asynchronous by default and your DOM didn't receive the server response yet..

You could use delegate to attach the event handlers, like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul.nav li a', function() {
    var page = this.href;

    $('#content').hide().load('pages/' + page + '.php').fadeIn('normal');

    //Wont Redirect
    return false;
});
```

or attach the event handlers on ajax's success callback function.

Hope it helps.